# How to ssh into a raspberry pi a middle of a field without wifi, ethernet, and usb?

Tags: wifi, ssh, remote

I have a raspberry pi on a drone and this drone is operated and tested in a middle of a field that does not have a wifi connection. I need to ssh into this raspberry pi from my laptop and I cannot use USB or Ethernet either since the raspberry pi is on a drone.

Wifi sharing from my mobile phone is not an option and has caused severe problems in the past. My idea is to make the raspberry pi into a router that does not actually connect to the internet through a modem, but just allows devices to connect to the raspberry pi. I only need my laptop to connect to it.

Essentially like how you connect your bluetooth earbuds to your phone but imagine via wifi.

I have tried tutorials that assume the raspberry pi will act as an actual wireless access point that connects to your home network. I don't need internet access, but just a direct connection to the raspberry pi.

Comment: What is this field? Does the drone are laying in the middle of it? You want to ssh into a RasPi without WiFi but you want to connect to use WiFi? What exactly do you want to use to connect to the RasPi?

Comment: The field is where I am testing the drone since I can't fly it inside. There will be no wifi internet access there.  You can create a hotspot on a raspberry pi and directly connect to the hotspot but I am not sure on how to do that.

Comment: See e.g. the Foundation's documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md, just leave out any routing, bridging, etc. Extremely easy to set up.

Comment: What you want is something called WiFi-Direct. There are a number of threads on this site on that topic. Type WiFI-Direct into the search box and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility for remote console access to a Pi 3 might be rfcomm over Bluetooth.

Comment: How does it work? May it be possible that could give an example? We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well this wold work, but using Digi XBee modules you could communicate with the RPi without wifi and directly using serial communications.  You would need two Digi Xbee's, one connected to the Serial of the RPi and the other to your computer.

Understanding how to connect to RPi serial using the GPIO pins
https://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection

Additional information to get you started on XBee
https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90001456-13/concepts/c_serial_communication.htm

Initial concern would be the quantity of data that needs to be transferred and power requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you can use an access point on the RasPi. I would suggest to use it. It has the advantage that you also can use it to remotely control the flying drone. You only need a simple access point without any other functionality like routing or bridging to another hotspot. Raspbian has everything "built-in" for an access point, you do not need any additional programs. Just configure it. How to do it you can look at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). Just follow the instructions in section **Setting up a stand alone access point**.